Excel- How to change colour of a cell based on the vale in another cell and the date range in other cell
I want to set a RAG in Column A2 to RED, Green or orange if the value in B is either REQ, FS, DEV, QA, Close & End Date for REQ is less than todays date then Green if not Red. Req Date is in C2 . FS date is in D2, Dev Date is in E2, QA date is in F2, Close date G2
=AND($B2="REQ",$C$2<$D$2) with fill set to Green, but not able to change the colour as the date changes

You can use multiple rules on one cell/row/column.

did below work as matter of interest @SagarByahatti?

Below/here refer.
Test control sheet - compare your method with below (conditional formatting applies/cells in question (col F) depend solely upon respective cell values in D & E.)

See if linked sheet not working for you either; if so then issue something else.
If you're not familiar with conditional formatting, see here and 'high-level' description below where I elaborate on above set up in more detail.
Considerations:
Possible issues may be something else - following are the likely suspects when I encounter such issues:

conflicting conditional format applies over same range/region. Place the rules in the correct priority order.
Ensure no 'stop rules' apply at a higher order of priority
Test the function you have in conditional format window in Excel itself (ideally same range you wish to apply the formatting to avoid cell reference issues unless you're fixing correctly)
Check that 'iterative calculation' option not on in Tools, Options, Calculation mode section. This may be masking circular references (see this for some info RE: iterative feature in general)
If you play around in VB you may have inadvertently disabled screen-updating; Application.ScreenUpdating = True to rectify (should reset after end of session/when you re-open excel, so unlikely to be cause if your issue has been persistent).
Perhaps more likely is calculation mode being on manual - see pt. 4 / link for how to rectify.

My guess is (1-2), incorrect function (3), maybe (6).

Setting conditional formatting up
(if well-versed/v. familiar with setting up correctly then this section less relevant/useful to you- I include as I don't know your skill level).
Basics: select range over which formatting will apply, click conditional formatting in ribbon and select function (not directly possible to achieve dependent conditional formatting for other types e.g. icons/bars etc. - cheat below).
Function must relate to first cell range over which formatting to apply.



Bonus
Cheat: get icons to show in cell but relate to values in other cells.
Linked sheet includes application of legacy 'camera' feature in Excel, which made the following possible (icon formats depend on cols D/E again).
This feature effectively 'mirrors' another part that you take a clipping of and shows live changes as/when they happen. Here for more detail. It's the only way I know / can readily think of to achieve.

Best of luck

̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿
